# Change chart bar series fill colour

Tags: excel, vba

I have an existing chart, and every time I change the source data (I run my model daily with new data), the colour of the bars go back to the default. Was wondering what is the code to change the fill?

This is my current code, I'm look to change the 2 named charts "CLoans" and "ULoans" to this colour specifically

[image: Excel colours]

```
Set CBorrowRng = wsSLSummary.Range("cbCorner").CurrentRegion
Set UBorrowRng = wsSLSummary.Range("ubCorner").CurrentRegion
Set CLoanRng = wsSLSummary.Range("clCorner").CurrentRegion
Set ULoanRng = wsSLSummary.Range("ulCorner").CurrentRegion

'Update chart source data
.ChartObjects("CBorrows").Chart.SetSourceData _
     Source:=CBorrowRng

.ChartObjects("UBorrows").Chart.SetSourceData _
    Source:=UBorrowRng
    
.ChartObjects("CLoans").Chart.SetSourceData _
    Source:=CLoanRng

.ChartObjects("ULoans").Chart.SetSourceData _
    Source:=ULoanRng
End With
```

Comment: What do you see when you start the macro recorder, format the series color, stop the macro recorder and look at the code? What do you get when you google how to change a chart series color with VBA?

Comment: Tried the macro recorder, it shows the selection on the chart, but it surprisingly doesn't give anything on when I change the colour. I've seen this code, but I don't know how to target the 2 specific charts by name

     With Activechart
     .SeriesCollection(7).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 153, 0)
     End with

Comment: Sheets("yoursheetname").ChartObjects(yourchartname").SeriesCollection(7).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 153, 0)

Comment: Giving me Run-time error 438 -- code -->
wsSLSummary.ChartObjects("CLoans").SeriesCollection(7).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 153, 0)